# Why is [ x * x for x in num] not resulting in a list in idle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

```
num = range(10)
[x * x for x in num]
```

should be all i need

Resulting in `range(0, 10)` in IDLE when executed. I want a list of squared characters. I've tried `range(0, 10)` still evals to itself

Comment: What do you mean by "resulting in"?

Comment: You're not assigning that list comprehension to anything.

Comment: How are you running this in IDLE? It should work just fine in the shell. But if you're running it in the editor, where is the output coming from? Is there a `print(num)` that you haven't mentioned? For tips, see [mre]. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want general tips.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below:

```
num = range(10)
lst= [x * x for x in num]
print(lst)
```

This will assign the result to `lst` variable.

If you are using jupyter notebook, you can try:

```
num = range(10)
lst= [x * x for x in num]
lst
```

Comment: I could be wrong but since he's using IDLE it should print even if he doesn't assign it to a variable

Comment: Yea i`m doing a course via skillsoft online. The online tutor is using jupyter notebook and he doesn`t assign to a variable.

Comment: @FionnMatthews so here assign the list to variable and the. Just type variable name and hit enter

Comment: @FionnMatthews Check the updated answer of that helps you.

Comment: @Fionn Hey, just to let you know why that formatting got messed up, you're using a grave accent/backtick instead of an apostrophe, and a grave is used in [Markdown](/editing-help) for inline code formatting.

Comment: Jupyter Notebook will print the result of an expression, so OP's code would actually work fine if he were using it. But OP said he's using IDLE, not Jupyter Notebook.